# MS Access - Grouping/Subdata Query results in a form

Tags: ms-access

I have created my first database in Access for a colleague, the purpose of this database is to allow my colleague to search for an individual that has skills/coverage in three key areas (Expertise Area, Industry Coverage,and Geographic Coverage). The database contains the following 5 Tables

1. Key Personal (KP) Table
2. Organisation Table
3. Area of Expertise Coverage
4. Geographic Coverage Table
5. Industry Coverage

The Three tables (Area of Expertise, Geographic Coverage and Industry Coverage) have the same data structure an example using the Geographic Coverage is shown below:

```
ID - KPID - AreaName  - GeoCoverage
1  - 1    - Melbourne - Yes
2  - 1    - Sydney    - No
3  - 1    - Hobart    - Yes
4  - 1    - Brisbane  - Yes
```

This then repeats for each Key Personal

The Key Personal Table has the following structure:

```
KPID - KPName - OrgID
1    - John   - 1
2    - James  - 1
3    - Molly  - 2
```

The Organisation Table has the following Structure

```
OrgID - OrgName
1     - Business 1
2     - Company 1
```

The Relationship between the Tables is shown below:

[image]

I have created a form to allow my Colleague to filter based on the three criteria, results are then shown in a sub-form, an example is shown in the picture below:
[image]

My question is whether there is a way to group the results by KPID, e.g. in the example above I have 12 lines for KP7 as they have Area of Expertise across multiple areas (and Area of Expertise has not been filtered for). This is only an issue when not all 3 criteria have been defined.

What i envisage this would look like is that KPID, Name and Organisation would be the top level line and then you could expand (using a + symbol) to view the various Area of Expertise of the individual.

As this is my first time using MS Access and creating a database any other comments/feedback around my database and data structure would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When two tables in Access have one or more fields in common,you can embed the datasheet from one table in another. This is called Subdatasheet. And this Subdatasheets can be nested up to eight levels. Using this you can have subdatasheets for organization,Area of Expertise,Geographic Coverage and Industry Coverage.
for a way to create subdatasheet refer to below [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-a-subdatasheet-900d1d30-5ea2-4e47-80a7-ddcb87a53d14):